# Symfony 3 can't move uploaded file

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I just start to learn Symfony 3 and I make a blog. 
I use Doctrine Entities to interact with the database. I'm on Xampp on Mac OS.

I created a form with a file input but when I want to upload the file it never moves where it should and in the database I record the path of the temp folder of Xampp.

**Here's the part of code in the Entity file :**

```
public function getFile()
{
  return $this->file;
}

public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
  $this->file = $file;
}

public function upload(){
  if(null === $this->file){
    return;
  }
  $name = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();

  $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $name);
  $this->image = $name;
}

public function getUploadDir(){
  return 'uploads/img';
}

public function getUploadRootDir(){
  return '/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}
```

**That's my form builder :**

```
class BlogType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('image', FileType::class)
            ->add('categorie', TextType::class)
            ->add('photographe', TextType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Boreales\PlatformBundle\Entity\Blog'
        ));
    }
}
```

**And the addAction from the controller :**

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
  //Création de l'entité
  $photo = new Blog();
  $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(BlogType::class, $photo);

  if($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()){
    $photo->upload();


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($photo);
    $em->flush();

    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Photo enregistrée.');
    var_dump($photo->getImage());
    //return new Response('Coucou');
    //return $this->redirectToRoute('galerie');
  }
  return $this->render('BorealesPlatformBundle:Blog:add.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView()
  ));
}
```

Can someone see where's the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

The code is OK in general, but you have problems with your `path`.

You now have such path

```
return '/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
```

Remove the leading forward slash from it

```
return '../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
```

**Forward slash** in the beginning is the **root** directory. You can't go above, it's on the top level.

But that's not gonna work either, because you need an absolute path to your directory. The best way to do it is to add this upload directory to the `config.yml`

```
# app/config/config.yml

# ...
parameters:
    upload_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/img'
```

And then use it. But you cannot directly access such parameters from the Model layer due to the design of it. So you need to pass it into the method you're calling.

```
//your controller
$photo->upload($this->getParameter('upload_directory'));
```

So you will have your methods in Entity look like

```
public function upload($path){
    if(null === $this->file){
        return;
    }
    $name = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();

    $this->file->move($path, $name);
    $this->image = $name;
}
```

That would be the best and the most appropriate way to do what you want to do. Hope it helps!